# dplyr: list of data frames output without for loop

Tags: r, list, for-loop, dplyr

The following code works fine. However, I want to get required output without for loop. Any thoughts

```
library(magrittr)
data("mtcars")

df1 <- mtcars %>% dplyr::filter(mpg > qsec*1/2)
df2 <- mtcars %>% dplyr::filter(mpg > qsec*2/2)

df <- vector("list", 2)

for(i in 1:2){
  df[[i]] <- mtcars %>% dplyr::filter(mpg > qsec*i/2)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need a `list` of `filter`ed datasets, we can use `map` from `purrr` (part of the `tidyverse` packages)

```
library(tidyverse)
map(1:2, ~ mtcars %>% 
                dplyr::filter(mpg > qsec * .x/2))
```

---

To have a single dataset, replace `map` with `map_df` and to have some kind of identifier, use the `.id`

```
map_df(1:2, ~ mtcars %>% 
                 dplyr::filter(mpg > qsec * .x/2), .id = 'grp')
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun for very useful answer. Would appreciate if you guide me how to stack all elements of the list into one data.frame or tibble. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

lapply() is a standard way to replace loops:

```
df <- lapply(1:2 / 2, function(x) dplyr::filter(mtcars, mpg > qsec*x))
```